# Unable to recover lost file with commit id

Tags: git

I have lost a file in my repo and I am unable to find the branch it belongs to. Since I couldn't remember the filename, I searched code that was in it.

A `git log` command retrieved nothing so I ran a
`git rev-list --branches | xargs git grep 'bq load'` and obtained the following output with the commit id:

```
6962fbb31fb4b80295fb01a0dbb1154939738c4f:shell/google_bq_ezfact_push.sh:bq load --null_marker="\N" --replace --source_format=CSV --autodetect ezdata.ez_userprofiles gs://bi_ezdata/ez_userprofiles.txt ID:NUMERIC,USERID:INTEGER,FIRSTNAME:STRING,LASTNAME:STRING,COMPANYNAME:STRING,ADDRESS:STRING,CITY:STRING,STATE:STRING,ZIPCODE:STRING,COUNTRY:INTEGER,USAGE:STRING,DELETED:BOOLEAN,CREATEDAT:TIMESTAMP,UPDATEDAT:TIMESTAMP,AUTOBUYCREDITS:BOOLEAN,AUTOBUYAMOUNTCREDITS:NUMERIC,AUTOBUYCREDITSLEVEL:NUMERIC
d887a6525c1cded916438a56ac2fb742c642e484:shell/google_bq_ezfact_push.sh:bq load --replace --source_format=CSV --autodetect ezdata.ez_users gs://bi_ezdata/ez_users.txt ID:INTEGER,USERNAME:STRING,PASSWORD:STRING,EMAIL:STRING,PHONENUMBER:STRING,SMPP_PRICE:NUMERIC,PRICE:NUMERIC,CF_PRICE:NUMERIC,KEYWORD_PRICE:NUMERIC,ALLOWDOWNLOADCONTACTS:BOOLEAN,CANCHANGEPACKAGE:BOOLEAN,OVERDUE:BOOLEAN,CREDIT:INTEGER,ADDITIONAL_CREDIT:INTEGER,CREDITLIMITPAYBYCHECK:INTEGER,CREATEDAT:TIMESTAMP,PRIVATELABELID:INTEGER,TIMEZONEPKEY:INTEGER,DELETED:BOOLEAN,UPDATEDAT:TIMESTAMP,UTILIZINGAPI:BOOLEAN
```

I attempted the following but to no avail

```
git checkout d887a6525c1cded916438a56ac2fb742c642e484^1 google_bq_ezfact_push.sh
error: pathspec 'google_bq_ezfact_push.sh' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

I get the same error if I specify the full path.

Now I found the filename, how can I retrieve it with the commit id? I am still unable to tell which branch the file is in (I was in master when I ran this command).

Comment: The filename is `shell/google_bq_ezfact_push.sh`.

Comment: Same error: `git checkout d887a6525c1cded916438a56ac2fb742c642e484^1 shell/google_bq_ezfact_push.sh
error: pathspec 'shell/google_bq_ezfact_push.sh' did not match any file(s) known to git`

Comment: Why `^1` in the commit?

Comment: Suggestion from a 3rd party.

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked successfully and allowed me to recover my file

```
git checkout d887a6525c1cded916438a56ac2fb742c642e484 shell/google_bq_ezfact_push.sh
```

Comment: Side note: the file is not necessarily in any branch. It is in some *commit* (including the one you selected). That commit may be in no branches, or in one or more branches.